# C# copy one control event to another programmatically

Tags: c#, event-handling, controls

I want to copy an event of control to another programmatically. For example, there is tab control and it has enter and leave event on it. Can I copy same event to panel view control programmatically?

Thanks

Comment: do you want the same action performed in both events? Or what do you mean by "copy same event" ?

Comment: Just add the same method on both controls event.